# Add with append appears twice

Tags: jquery, html, append

I use append to add another div

```
 $('#'+ number).append('<div id="descc'+number+'" class="backgroundImage" style="font-size:10px; height:13px; color:#fff; background-color:#000;" align="center">'+ descA+'</div>');
```

The div appears two times and remove() doesn't work , any ideas?

```
function getDesc(number) {
    $.getJSON('getDescription.php?number=' + number, function(des) {
        descA = des;
        $('#' + number).append('<div id="descc' + number + '" class="backgroundImage" style="font-size:10px; height:13px; color:#fff; background-color:#000;" align="center">' + descA + '</div>');
    });
}

function cargarProyectos(cant, col) {
    for (i = 1; i <= cant; i++) {
        $('#proyectos').append('<div class="backgroundImage" id="' + i + '" style="position:relative; float:left; width:186px; height:150px; background-image: url(../CMS/_class/image.php?id=' + i + ' ); margin-top: 10px;margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; cursor:hand;"></div>');
        $('#' + i).html('<div class="backgroundImage" style="font-size:10px; height:13px; color:#fff; background-color:#000;" align="center">PROYECTO ' + i + '</div>');
        getDesc(i);
        if (!(i % col) && i != 1) {
            $('#proyectos').append('<div class="scroll"  id="detalle' + Math.floor((i / col)) + '" style="position:relative; white-space: nowrap;display:none;  width:100%; height:0px; background-color:#e8e8e8; margin-bottom:10px;">            </div>');
        } else if (i == cant) {
            $('#proyectos').append('<div class="scroll" id="detalle' + Math.floor((i / col) + 1) + '" style="position:relative; display:none;white-space: nowrap; width:100%; height:0px; background-color:#e8e8e8; margin-bottom:10px;"></div>');
        }
    }
}

function windowSize() {
    winW = $('#proyectos').width();
    posicionDetalle = Math.floor(winW / 160);
    for (i = 1; i <= cantProyectos; i++) {
        $('#descc' + i).remove();
        $('#' + i).remove();
        if (i == cantProyectos) {
            cargarProyectos(cantProyectos, posicionDetalle);
        }
    }
    attachClickEvent();
}
```

Comment: please add more relevant code.

Comment: please add the full code so we can view what is going on

Comment: Need the relevant HTML. An example in jsfiddle.net would be helpful too.

Comment: When I used .html() doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are after some ideas, here goes mine. I am guessing since we have no `HTML` also we do not see where you call which function.

But the name `windowSize()` suggests me that you might be calling it on window resize particularly that you are working with the current size of the window.

This makes me even more sure that you must call it in `resize()`. Therefore, it can be sometimes called twice (the number is in fact no guaranteed and it certainly depends on the browser being used) --- this might be it.

To sort out your problem just check if it exists before deciding to add it.

Also in your `windowSize()` method the below test is unnecessarily in side the for loop - move it outside the for loop (on the way dropping the if statement) placing it just after it.

```
    if (i == cantProyectos) {
        cargarProyectos(cantProyectos, posicionDetalle);
    }
```